# Managed Service Account has "Everyone:Change password" ACE by default

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have created a service account using the `Add-ADComputerServiceAccount` cmdlet and bound it to a computer account using `Install-ADServiceAccount`. When looking into the ACL of the created service account object, I noticed that the "Everyone" group has the "Change Password" permission assigned for this object, while "SELF" mysteriously has not:

[image: ACL for the Managed Service Account object]

This looks like a security problem and a denial-of-service attack vector. Why is this so? Does it have to stay this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the default security ACL on a normal user account.  You'll notice that Everyone has Change Password on those as well.  But everyone can't just go and change each others passwords.

Remember that **Change Password** and **Reset Password** are two different permissions.  Changing a password is something the user does for itself and requires providing the current password as part of the process.  Resetting a password is something done administratively by another user and doesn't require the current password.

*Edit*: Nope, I was wrong about the underlying reason.  Microsoft Article [KB242795](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242795) explains better the underlying reason for the permission.

From the article:

> The Everyone group has Change Password permissions on all computer and user objects so that unauthenticated or "anonymous" users or computers are able to change their passwords when they expire without having to be authenticated first. If the anonymous user is denied the ability to change passwords, the user would be unable to change the password without logging on.

Comment: A concise answer with a reference - perfect, thanks.

Comment: Well, this aged poorly: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/new-windows-10-vulnerability-allows-anyone-to-get-admin-privileges/ (Change Password accepts the NTLM hash in lieu of the actual current password, therefore Everyone with your hash can change your password.)

Comment: Did it though? The SAM database being readable by unprivileged users was clearly a mistake and will likely be fixed in the next patch cycle or an out of band release. It doesn't really change the reality that users with expired passwords will need a way to change that password while unauthenticated assuming they still know the old password.